# My project files in Visual Studio 2010 hijacked how to recover them

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Once I have opened the same project from different locations from my PC. Then `VS2010` thrown some error like files got `hijacked`. That is still there. How to recover the `working project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer from here...
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21299853